# Limit in two variables

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to prove this limit:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}(3xy+1,e^y+2)=(1,3)$$
I know the definition, but can't bound the norm.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that directly from the definition?  If so, what are you allowed to use about the exponential function?

Comment: @Ricky: Yes, using definition. Basic properties... what do you think?

Comment: Which basic properties, though? If you can use some fact like "e^y < 1 + y + y^2 for |y| < 1", it's quite easy!

Comment: You are right, it´s quite easy. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reduce the number of unanswered questions, I answer this:

Let $\epsilon\gt 0$. You know that $$\lim_{y\to 0} e^y = 1,$$ so, exist $\delta'>0$ such that $$|e^y-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$ Take $$\delta=\min\left \{ \delta',\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{6}}\right\}.$$ Thus, if $||(x,y)||<\delta$,
$$\begin{align*}
||(3xy+1,e^y+2)-(1,3)||&\leq |3xy| + |e^y-1|\\
&\leq 3||(x,y)||^2+|e^y-1|\\
&< 3 \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{6} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
&=\epsilon. \end{align*}$$
The last inequality follows because $|y|\leq ||(x,y)||$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $u(x,y)=(3xy+1,e^y+2)$, hence $u(0,0)=(1,3)$. Since one is interested in the limit of $u$ at $(0,0)$, one can (and we will) assume that $\|(x,y)\|\le1$ where $\|\ \|$ denotes the Euclidean norm.

Using $|xy|\le |y|$ and $|e^y-1|\le2|y|$ for every $(x,y)$ such that $\|(x,y)\|\le1$, and $|y|\le\|(x,y)\|$ for every $(x,y)$, one gets
$$
|u(x,y)-u(0,0)|\le5\|(x,y)\|.
$$

Comment: easier :) +1 some kind of Lipschitzity arround $0$